# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'System.IConvertible'. error

Tags: c#

I dont know why I am getting error as

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

here is the code:-

```
if (dtExcel.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Hid_Mode.Value = "M";
        dtExcel.Rows[0]["Emp Code"] = CF.ExecuteDT("Select Mkey from Emp_Eval_Proc_hdr where " +
                                                    " Emp_Code = '" + Convert.ToInt32(dtExcel.Rows[0]["Emp Code"]) + "'");}
```

why ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because `System.Data.DataTable` is not derived from System.IConvertible. `DataTable` is derived from `System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent` which is derived from `System.Object`.

I think `CF.ExecuteDT` returns `DataTable` instance and you try to set `dtExcel.Rows[0]["Emp Code"]` to that instance.